# How do I find point locations on a graph from edges and one known point position?

Tags: graph-theory

I have been given a collection of nodes and edges such that each node connects to every other node by an edge. All the edge lengths are known. One of the nodes locations (x,y) is known, but the rest are unknown. Find the location of all the unknown nodes.
I am pretty lost on this problem I was just wondering if someone could point me in the right direction because I am really stumped right now.

Comment: You actually need at least two other pieces of information to avoid having the graph rotate about the known point or become its own reflection. But the edge lengths to each two other points along with the known point should allow definite construction of triangles to place those other points apart from that.

Comment: The only other information he gave us is that the 2D plane is bounded.

Comment: Depending on where the bounds are, that might be enough. You would need to start the construction with a triangle set arbitrarily and then check how to rotate and reflect the final network to stay within the boundary. It might be as simple as the triangle with the longest edge from the known point determining the initial orientation and parity.